# d3.jsv4: wheel zoom and click zoom, transformed data does not sync

Tags: d3.js

I zoomed my graph by clicking a button, and it worked fine. But when I switched to zoom by my mouse wheel, the value of 'event.transform' was not the latest translate and scale, but still initial. Below is my main code:

```
import { ZoomBehavior, zoom, zoomIdentity, zoomTransform } from 'd3-zoom';
...
const zoom = zoom();
svg.call(
    zoom.on('zoom', function(){
        graph.attr('transform', event.transform);  // line: 1
    })
)
...
// triggered by click
clickZoom(dir: 1|-1){
    const view = {...zoomTransform(graph.node())}
    const size = graph.node().getBBox();
    let newScale = view.k * (1 + zoomFactor * dir);
    view.x += size.width * (view.k - newScale)/2;
    view.y += size.height * (view.k - newScale)/2;
    view.k = newScale;
    interpolateZoom([view.x, view.y], view.k);
}
interpolateZoom(
    translate: [number, number],
    scale: number,
  ) {
    const t = transition()
      .duration(200)
      .ease();
    return graph
      .transition(t)
      .call(
        zoom.transform,
        zoomIdentity.translate(translate[0], translate[1]).scale(scale),
      );
  }
```

If I zoom my graph by wheel zoom, then click the button to zoom, the value of `zoomTransform` is also not the actual.

When I clicked the button to zoom, I consoled the value of 'event.transform', it was always correct, but when I switched to wheel zoom, its value changed to the initial value at first.

So how `zoomTransform` and `event.transform` values can be correctly synced?

Comment: This question was resolved by myself. I didn't really understand `The zoom transform is now stored on any elements to which the zoom behavior has been applied`, so actually the transform is stored on the element `svg`, not the element `graph`.

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. Thanks a lot.